# Automatic, bootable drive wiper

Tags: automation, wiping, bootable

I'm looking for a bootable tool that erases all data on all hdds in a computer that does not need any interaction whatsoever.

On my work, we now and then get quite a few, old, crappy PCs that are for the process of either trash or donation. It's quite a tedious process of setting up monitors, keyboards and mice just for a drive wipe.

So, in a perfect world where unicorn reigns supreme, I would love some form of boot able USB or CD if that is the only option, that has no menus, no confirms it just wipes anything that can hold a memory, and does the random bit thing so it's harder to recover the data. And say shuts down the PC afterwards, to indicate it's completion. Is there any? I know already of software like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/), and it's a close match. Just not quite there!

Comment: So, what is Dan's Boot & Nuke missing? (apart, obviously, from unicorns)  And, do you really means drive**R** wiper, as in "leave the o/s, but remove the drivers", or just "drive wiper"?

Comment: @Sodori From the context of your question I understood that you want to clean all data away and not just the hardware drivers, so I clarified your question to that end. Please add more Detail as to why DBAN does not fit your needs.

Comment: From my experience, DBAN usually requires at least some input (keyboard required), thus making it not fit the requirements.

Comment: Make a note of the standard keystrokes required in DBAN. Then all you need to do is connect a keyboard each time, wait for DBAN to boot, press the keys, and power off. It doesn't eliminate all the peripherals, but it's a lot easier than connecting them all each time.

Comment: Are your machines set up for booting from the network? http://www.serenux.com/2014/05/howto-setup-dariks-boot-and-nuke-dban-to-automatically-erase-storage-devices-via-pxe-boot/

Answer (score 0):

As long as the computers are set to boot off of USB or CD you can use DBAN.

I just downloaded the latest version of DBAN and changed the ISOLINUX.CFG file from

"PROMPT 1" to "PROMPT 0"

and

"DEFAULT dban" to "DEFAULT autonuke"

then recreated the ISO file using Ultra ISO, but you could use IMGBurn or 7Zip. I'm not sure if it will shut down after though.